# exclude product with available tag

Tags: wp-query, tags, tax-query

I have classic WP_Querry:

```
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

with

```
$args = [
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'  => 500,
    'product_cat' => 'cars',
];
```

If I want products with certain tags, i can add 'product_tag' => 'wherever_tag_i_need'. How I can get all products that doesn`t have certain tags in this product category?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a `tax_query` with the `NOT IN` operator.

```
WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 500,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( 'cars' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( 'whatever_tag_i_dont_need' ),
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
) )
```

The above will request all posts in assigned to term `cars` that don't have any tags with the slug `whatever_tag_i_dont_need`. There's other comparison operator too. For more information please reference the docs below:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: This works for turnover) This code displays all products from the category with the tag to be removed

Comment: @OcsanaMurzinova use 'operator' instead of 'compare'